# Parse: One app on parse.com will be accessed by multiple iOS apps. Does it work?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

we are about to finish our first app with parse.com. This first app is for the enduser. PushNotifications and everything are working fine.

Now we want to create an app for our admins to manage everything. We want it to be a separate app. Therefore I was wondering: will this be possible? Two apps connecting to one data collection on parse.

Especially regarding the PushNotifications. Admins should also receive a push notification on the new admin app (e.g. new member joins and needs to be activated).

Has anyone ever done something like this?
Or do we need to build the admin part into the main app?

The thing is we will need a third app, which is for business owners to manage their listing on our main app. So the same problem/question will apply then.

Looking forward to your feedback.

Txs!

Answer (score 1):

Yes same Parse app ID can be used by different platforms/apps, that is basic concept of Parse. You can even use it in web, iOS, Android, etc with same parse app. This should not be a problem.

You might need to modify you parse data structure tough to suit your admin app requirement.

Check https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#roles

Comment: Did you got what your are looking for?